# Making Blockingcollection observable

Tags: c#, wpf, blockingcollection

I have a list that is bound to a blockingcollection in my viewmodel

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PlantControllers}"
```

and property

```
  public BlockingCollection<PLANTCONTROLLER> PlantControllers
        {
            get { return _plant.PlantControllers; }

        }
```

What is the easiest way of making a blockingcollection observable, cant seem to find any good examples out there

Comment: Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966629/how-to-make-blockingcollection-observable

Comment: Thanks,Not sure how wrapping a observablecollection inside a blockingcollection would make it thread safe though

Answer (score 2):

Use your `BlockingCollection` as an "entry point" for data going into your UI thread using a producer/consumer pattern.

Your threads all add items to the `BlockingCollection`, and on your UI thread use a timer to occasionally check to see if there are new items. If there are, take them and add them to an `ObservableCollection`.

Another option could be to have each thread have a reference to the UI thread's dispatcher, and use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to queue up the method that takes from the `BlockingCollection` and adds to the `ObservableCollection`.